# ASP.NET splitting out membership and using the repository pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, repository-pattern

I am building an application using asp.net mvc, DI, IoC, TDD as a bit of a learning exercise.

For my data access I am using the repository pattern. Now I am looking at membership and how this can work with the repository pattern. I am currently using a Linq to Sql repository but don't want to be tied to SQL Server for membership.

Secondly, I am looking to split out membership into a number of services:

- AuthenticationService - identify the user
- AuthorizationService - what can they do
- PersonalizationService - profile

The personalization service will be what really defines a "customer" in my application and each customer will have a unique id/username that ties back to the AuthenticationService - thus, allowing me to use the default ASP.NET Membership provider, roll my own or use something like Open ID.

Is this a good approach? I don't want to reinvent the wheel but would rather these important parts of my application follow the same patterns as the rest.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [RIA Authentication, Roles, and Profiles service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707361%28VS.91%29.aspx)s.. no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Forgive my ignorance but I can't see how RIA will help. If I am using multiple clients e.g. mvc and silverlight I can see how this would be useful. However, since it is built on top of the standard membership in ASP.NET it seems it changes how the authentication service is exposed to my application, but not how it actually works, or how it interacts with my model. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, to achieve what I wanted was quite a simple process. I haven't implemented the AuthorizationService yet but this will follow a similar pattern.

My authentication service is quite simple:

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    bool IsValidLogin(string username, string password);
}
```

There will be a CreateUser method but I haven't implemented this yet.

Creating an authentication service using the standard membership provider is a simple task:

```
public class AspNetAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public bool IsValidLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        return Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
    }
}
```

If I want to swap out the default SqlMembershipProvider with my own then I just need to change web.config. In order to support different types of authentication (perhaps forms auth and open id) I can just create a controller action for each and call the appropriate IAuthenticationService.ValidateUser implementation before setting an auth cookie.

The authentication process if for identifying the "user". In order to get the "Customer" I am using a PersonalizationService. The interface for this is again quite simple:

```
public interface IPersonalizationService {
    Customer GetCustomer(string username);
}
```

This returns my customer (with addresses, past orders - the stuff we really care about). The GetCustomer method will create a customer object if one doesn't exist with the passed in username. So if using standard forms auth a customer will be created anyway during registration. If using something like OpenID, the first time they login a customer object will be created and linked to their OpenID username (hence the reason for separating what an authenticated "user" is from a "customer".

This process also works well for anonymous checkout since I can create an in memory customer object for "guest" customers, and finally persist this to the database if they make a purchase. In this case, I don't have a user (cause they didn't authenticate) but I do have a customer.

I am quite happy with this implementation. I think I will roll my own Membership Provider (since it's not really that difficult) and I would like to use the repository pattern for the data access. Interested to hear any opinions / suggestions on this approach.

Some resources I have used:

http://noahblu.wordpress.com/2009/02/19/custom-membershipprovider-using-repository-dependency-injection-pattern-magic/

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/11/CreateCustomMembershipProviderASPNETWebsiteSecurity.aspx

http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/837990/mobile

http://mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx

Comment: This appears to be the same approach used by Ron Conery when he refactored the standard ASP.NET Membership to adopt OpenId (see http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-16-membership-redo-with-openid) which I quite liked. One thing that I struggled with (and still am) is....once you have authenticated a user via OpenId, do you create an entry in the ASP.NET membership table for them? Or would you maintain a separate table specifically? Interested in what you ended up doing.

Comment: @James - working on the basis of users (authentication) and profiles (personalization) we would have a separate table for our internal authentication system and a separate table for our profiles. Profiles hold a reference to the authentication username. This could be a username in our internal users table or it could be an openid claim url. The idea is that regardless of how the user authenticates we can load their profile. Hope that makes sense.